# Running a Javascript function after a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to programming and javascript.

What I want to do :
Javascript function running on pageload, in this case showVideo(). I want to run this function for a say 10 seconds and then move to the next function.

```
function(){
     dostuff();
  // dostuff for 10 seconds
  // now stop dostuff
  // donewstuff();
}  

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="screen" id="screen-1" data-video="vid/river.mp4">
            <img src="img/bird.jpg" class="big-image" />
        </div>
        <div class="screen" id="screen-2" data-video="vid/sim.mp4">
            <img src="img/spider.jpg" class="big-image" />
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>

<script>
        $(function(){
            var 
                BV,
                videoPlayer,
                BV = new $.BigVideo();
                BV.init();
                showVideo();
                BV.getPlayer();



            function showVideo() {
                BV.show($('#screen-1').attr('data-video'),{ambient:true});
                $('#screen-1').find('.big-image').transit({'opacity':0},500)
                setTimeout(function(){showVideo2},40000);
            }
            function showVideo2() {
                BV.show($('#screen-2').attr('data-video'),{ambient:true});
                $('#screen-2').find('.big-image').transit({'opacity':0},500)
            }
```

I tried :

```
setTimeout(function(){showVideo2},40000)
```

but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `showVideo2` without `()` is just a function *reference*, not an executing call to the function. You either want `setTimeout(showVideo2, 40000)` which passes the function reference to `setTimeout` for calling later, or `setTimeout(function(){ showVideo2() }, 40000)` which passes the anonymous function by reference to `setTimeout` and when that anon func is executed it will in turn execute `showVideo2`.

Comment: Really the question should be titled "How do I run on function from another function after a certain amount of time". If you were truly running a function after one another you would need to use callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually call the function.  Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    showVideo2();
}, 40000);
```

Note the `()` in `showVideo2()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()`

```
var stopped = false;
setTimeout(function() {
  stopped = true;
}, 10000);

while (!stopped) {
  // Do stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would like to invoke showVideo and then 40s later invoke showVideo2.  What you have is close, however you are not invoking showVideo2 in your timeout.

You have two solutions that would fix it:

Change

```
        function showVideo() {
            BV.show($('#screen-1').attr('data-video'),{ambient:true});
            $('#screen-1').find('.big-image').transit({'opacity':0},500)
            setTimeout(function(){showVideo2},40000);
        }
```

To either:

```
        function showVideo() {
            BV.show($('#screen-1').attr('data-video'),{ambient:true});
            $('#screen-1').find('.big-image').transit({'opacity':0},500)
            setTimeout(showVideo2,40000);
        }
```

or:

```
        function showVideo() {
            BV.show($('#screen-1').attr('data-video'),{ambient:true});
            $('#screen-1').find('.big-image').transit({'opacity':0},500)
            setTimeout(function(){showVideo2(); },40000);
        }
```

Without testing this should work.  Please comment if you have any questions.